# What should a WCF service return when a client requests a list?

Tags: c#, wcf

Simple question, multiple possibilities:

- `ICollection<T>`
- `IEnumerable<T>`
- `List<T>`
- `IList<T>`
- `Array`

What are the advantages and disadvantages over each other? Are there performance/security issues?

Comment: List will be returned as array anyway

Comment: @Taumantis: that is true for JSON but not for SOAP.

Comment: @John Saunders good to know

Answer (score 5):

It really doesn't matter what the service returns since it will be serialized anyway. But if you're sharing the interfaces between the server and client, `IEnumerable<T>` is typical since it covers all the other suggestions. If you have a finite set you could also use `IList<T>` but I would avoid `Array`.

Comment: Funny thing is, I often see Array in WCF/SOAP service specifications. Yes, I assumed IEnumerable is the 'right' way.

Answer (score -2):

Kind of a broad based question, but it really depends on how you are consuming the object on the client side. If you're just dumping this into a JSON array, an Array would work fine, but if you need the extra methods that the other implementations have, serialize those specific objects for which you need.

Comment: -1: with SOAP, it doesn't matter what the service returns. The client decides how to receive it. The service is simply returning XML that conforms to an XSD "`sequence`". The client will decide what that means. Ask yourself: what would a Java client do with the return value from the service?

Comment: @JohnSaunders WCF can return JSON, wrapped in a SOAP response.

Comment: @ohmusama: I'm aware of that - I just got through working on a set of such services. Even in the case of JSON, it doesn't matter. I have services returning `IEnumerable<T>` and other returning `List<T>` and they make perfect JSON arrays.

Comment: @JohnSaunders are you aware of an easy way to respond as either JSON or traditional XML from the same service endpoint? I recently was doing this, but ended up making a dummy JSON service that instantiated and invoked the first, but responded as JSON.

Comment: Offhand, I don't know how. You can, of course, use two different endpoints which expose the same contract and call the same code, but have different settings: one SOAP, one JSON.